# Which language do you speak best or the best?

Tags: grammaticality

Look at this dialogue:

> -What languages do you speak?
>
> -Persian, English and French.
>
> -Which one do you speak the best?
>
> -English.

About "the best", a native tells me he finds using *the* quite unnatural.

My search shows it is obvious that the omission of "the" outnumbers the inclusion of "the" considerably. Nevertheless, I am sure I have read this usage, *the best as an adverb*, in such sentences in a number of educational materials.

I would like to know the comments of natives on this. Is it wrong or unnatural?

Links are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

> the best

is quite natural, since it is presumably one from a choice of more than one.

> Q: Persian or French, which do you speak better?
>   A: Persian.
>   Q: French or English, which are you better at speaking?
>   A: English.
>   Q: So between Persian, French and English, you speak English **the** best?
>   A: Yes!